# Is it more performant to use Raphael.transformPath or Element.transform() with Raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm working on an SVG-based web app that has a number of SVG elements that need to be moved around the SVG canvas. When transforming SVG elements, is it faster from a performance perspective to use Raphael.JS's [`Raphael.transformPath`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.transformPath) or [`Element.transform`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a doubt, `Element.transform` is hundreds of times faster than `Raphael.transformPath`. I believe that this is because `Raphael.transformPath` does string operations that can take quite a bit of time, especially with longer, more complex paths. `Element.transform` merely applies an attribute to the corresponding SVG element and lets the browser do the heavy lifting. A jsPerf is available here: http://jsperf.com/raphaeljs-transformpath-vs-svg-transforms